# Customize date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need date and time in this format in javascript.

```
2016/02/17-14:31:36
```

Currently I am using

```
var data = new Date();
```

But this gives  `Date {Fri Feb 26 2016 18:38:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}`

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What did you find on google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: `data.toLocaleString()` and `date.toLocaleDateString()` might be of some help. Go to browser console and type in `var date=new Date();` and then type `date.` browser console will give you all available functions, then choose accordingly. (on Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = new Date(),
   year = d.getFullYear(),
   month = ('0'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
   day = ('0'+d.getDay()).slice(-2),
   hour = ('0'+d.getHours()).slice(-2),
   minute = ('0'+d.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
   second = ('0'+d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

var dateString = year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'-'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
```

Next time, please google yourself.  Thanks.

**Edit**
Now it also has those leading zero's.